# How to use puppeteer to hook into powerbi report loaded event

Tags: powerbi, puppeteer

I am embedding a power bi report using pupeteer/chromium quite happily and then save that as a screenshot/pdf. However, a late breaking requirement requires me to be able to hook the report's onloaded event.

I have the following code snippet which is the template I use to hook up the event; the report is embedding, but the 'report.on' event is not firing, (In reality I'm trying to set some visuals and other stuff, not just log text.)

```
       await page.evaluate((configdata) => {
             const models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
             const config = {
                         ...
             };

             const report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config)

             report.on('loaded', function () {
                 console.log('loaded report')
             });

       },
       configdata);
```

I've looked at "exposeFunction()" but couldn't get it hooked to this event (or others).

Would some please tell me what I'm missing; there must be way to do this, but I'm missing how to tie the report object (instantiated from within the IFrame, to it's event from withing the puppeteer function. However, JS/Node is not my primary discipline, hell it's not even my second!

PS: I know (and have got working) passing filters into to the configuration; but that is not quite good enough from the aethetics point of view (on screen visuals are not set!)

Any help/pointers - very greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you know that it's not firing? are you expecting the console.log to work on the node side?

Comment: Hi
I'm running `headless:false` showing the browser. With the above snippet, I would have expected that console.log to be written into the console (F12); it's not. I've therefore inferred (potentially incorrectly) that the event has not fired.

Comment: That' feature is marked as "fails in Firefox" https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/1623bef26452f5f90c899ca159f237e074c765b0/test/network.spec.js#L706 you'll need to wait for that feature to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

We've kept with passing the filters into the configuration whne embedding the report.
short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you can use page.evaluate and create a Promise which will be resolved when the embed loaded event will be triggered. Then you can await for your loadEmbed function:

```
async function loadEmbed(page, config) {
return page.evaluate(async (config) => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

            var embed = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

            embed.off("loaded");
            embed.on("loaded", function () {
                resolve(true);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
}, config);
```

}